# How config git email notification

Tags: email, git, gitolite

Could your advice information (script) to config git notification.

We have many projects and team working with them. It will be better if team member could get email notification when another push.

Answer (score 1):

See [How to setup post-receive-email Git hook with Gitolite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055190/how-to-setup-post-receive-email-git-hook-with-gitolite) for an example.

With Gitolite V3, you can set any hook you want, as detailed in "[gitolite post receive hook for specific bare repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206290/gitolite-post-receive-hook-for-specific-bare-repo)".